# batch script to parse txt file with delimiter as semicolon

Tags: windows, batch-file

my text file is as shown below:

```
H;SEQUENCENUMMER;TIMESTAMP;VERSION;VALIDITY_FLAG;SID
D;1077;1383519656;"20.0.8-2";1;;
D;1079;1383519657;"20.0.8-2";2;;
```

i want to parse this using windows batch program and output file will look like as beloW:

```
H  SEQUENCENUMMER  TIMESTAMP  VERSION  VALIDITY_FLAG  SID
D  1077  1383519656  "20.0.8-2"  1
D  1078  1383519657  "20.0.8-3"  2
```

something like a tab delimited

pls suggest

Comment: Would this be outputted into a table format so its aligned? I can easily do a search for ; and replace with a space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Get a tab character
    for /f tokens^=^*^ delims^= %%t in ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x09"') do set "tab=%%t" 

    rem For each line in text file, replace ; with a tab    
    (for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (plaintext.txt) do (
        set "line=%%l"  
        echo !line:;=%tab%!
    )) > output.txt

    endlocal
```

Comment: this is the answer I like most so far.+1

Comment: this is failing when there is space in any of columnn value

Comment: @user2215906: sorry, my fault. I forgot to include `token` clause in for command. Updated

Comment: Effectively the best answer.

Comment: I'm intrigued on what basis this is the best answer? Surely not on grounds of legibility with all those carets (^) and percents? Nor on grounds of simplicity with double for loops? Anyone? Performance? I doubt it. Genuinely intrigued! :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Well, in my opinion, in terms of legibility and performance, the "best" answer is "use tr/gsar/sed/...." or any of the amazing tools there are available. But, hey, doing it in batch allows you to use a lot of carets and percents ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist output.txt del output.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "Your Text File.txt"') do (set $line=%%a
                                               echo !$line:;=   !>>output.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested for-loops as follows:

```
@echo off
echo.|set a=>outfile.txt
for /f %%A in (infile.txt) do (
    for %%B in (%%A) do (
        echo.|set /P ="%%B    ">>outfile.txt
    )
    echo.>>outfile.txt
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't really seem to be parsing anything, you are just replacing semicolons with tabs. You can use VBScript to do this. Save the following as "process.vbs"

```
Option Explicit
Dim Line,Regex

Set RegEx = new RegExp
Regex.Pattern = ";"
Regex.Global=True

Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
   Line = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
   Line = Regex.Replace(Line,VBTab)
   WScript.Echo Line
Loop
```

Then you can run it like this:

```
vbscript /nologo process.vbs < yourfile > newfile
```